# What's the easiest way to make a CC.NET local trigger to execute a program?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, cctray

When the build fails, I'd like to execute a program that shoots me in the head with [this](http://b.ai/b8e).  I've written the program already - I just need it to run when I break the build.

CCTray has the option to make a sound or icon - but not to run a file.  Any simple ideas?  I'd rather this not be an all day project.  :)

Answer (score 1):

CCTray allows you to run commands.  In CCTry, go to File | Settings and then click on the Exec tab.

Comment: Note that this was added after the 1.4.4 release (likely with version 1.5.)

Answer (score 0):

If you run Outlook, you can set up a rule that runs an application whenever you receive an email saying the build is broken. Just follow the rules wizard and you will find it (in Ootlook 2007 it's on the 3rd page of the wizard, in the select action part).

Comment: I don't get an email, or run outlook - really trying to play off of CCTray here, but it looks like I'll have to write my own program to check build status.

Thinking of contributing an "execute program" feature in CCTray instead since I think it's open source.

Answer (score 0):

[Cradiator](http://cradiator.codeplex.com/) has functionality to monitor build servers and do stuff when a build breaks. It doesn't have code to run an executable but it would be a cinch to download the code, change it and get what you want. Here's what I think is the quickest path to getting this done:

- Download the source for [Cradiator](https://github.com/PandaWood/Cradiator)
- Edit the [DiscJockey.cs class](https://github.com/PandaWood/Cradiator/blob/master/src/Cradiator/Audio/DiscJockey.cs)
- Add 1 line of code that starts your program (line 34) eg:
- Configure Cradiator to monitor your build server (ie edit *app.config* and add your url) and run

```
if (newlyBrokenBuilds.Any())
{ // Add a line of code to start your program here eg
  Process.Start("C:\\myprogram.exe");
}
```